# Does someone really need to play Harry in the Dresden Files Cooperative Card Game?

Tags: dresden-files

My boyfriend and I are looking at the [Dresden Files cooperative card game](http://www.evilhat.com/home/dresden-files-cooperative-card-game/), based on the books by Jim Butcher.

However, a serious problem we both have with the idea of the game is that someone must play the eponymous Harry Dresden.  That seems at best boring and at worst really poor game design.  Has anyone played this game without Harry Dresden in play?

Comment: I find it a little surprising that you'd want a Dresden game without wanting to play as Harry. That's a little like getting an Iron Man game but not wanting to play as Tony Stark... If you don't like the IP enough to want to play as the titular character, maybe looking at a different game might lead to more fun.

Comment: The thing I really like about the Dresden Files is the worldbuilding and the supporting characters.  Dresden himself ranges from boring to cringe-inducing, but Molly, Sanya, Mouse, Michael, Thomas, etc really make the series for me.

Comment: Fair enough, I've only read the first few books so wasn't too familiar w/ the other characters.

Answer (score 7):

I'm the publisher. You CAN play without Harry's deck, but you run the risk of having an unsolvable board if you do.

Harry's Talent has the ability to rearrange parts of the board in order to move things closer that need to be cleared before other parts of the scenario can be taken on. So on some boards you might not need that — random shuffle being what it is. On others, it's make-or-break. The reason why it's necessary to play Harry might not be in the rules (frankly it's not necessary to explain the why in the rules); the statement "Always include the Harry Dresden deck" however is.

Answer (score 1):

There are also a lot of cards in the various book decks that have an effect specifically on Harry (good or bad), that wouldn't do anything if Harry wasn't in the game.  That would throw off the balance I worked very hard to create.

He is needed for both practical and aesthetic reasons.